# How to apply styles to react-burger-menu button with styled-components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I would like to use `styled-components` in a React app to create a menu component that contains the styles in the same file thus making it very modular. I'm using `react-burger-menu` for the menu. Everything works correctly if I wrap `BurgerMenu` in a styled `div` like so (styles copied from `react-burger-menu` README.md):

```
import React from 'react';
import { slide as BurgerMenu } from 'react-burger-menu';
import styled from 'styled-components';


const StyledBurgerMenu = styled.div`
  /* Position and sizing of burger button */
  .bm-burger-button {
    position: fixed;
    width: 36px;
    height: 30px;
    left: 36px;
    top: 36px;
  }

  /* Color/shape of burger icon bars */
  .bm-burger-bars {
    background: #373a47;
  }

  /* Position and sizing of clickable cross button */
  .bm-cross-button {
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
  }

  /* Color/shape of close button cross */
  .bm-cross {
    background: #bdc3c7;
  }

  /* General sidebar styles */
  .bm-menu {
    background: #373a47;
    padding: 2.5em 1.5em 0;
    font-size: 1.15em;
  }

  /* Morph shape necessary with bubble or elastic */
  .bm-morph-shape {
    fill: #373a47;
  }

  /* Wrapper for item list */
  .bm-item-list {
    color: #b8b7ad;
    padding: 0.8em;
  }

  /* Individual item */
  .bm-item {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  /* Styling of overlay */
  .bm-overlay {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
`;


export class Menu extends React.Component {
  showSettings(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <StyledBurgerMenu>
        <BurgerMenu>
          <a id="home" className="menu-item" href="/">Home</a>
          <a id="about" className="menu-item" href="/about">About</a>
        </BurgerMenu>
      </StyledBurgerMenu>
    );
  }
}

export default Menu;
```

Now this is of course totally okay. However, to learn a lesson and make things a bit more elegant, I'd like to get rid of nesting `BurgerMenu` inside of `StyledBurgerMenu` by passing the former to `styled()`. However, this leads to the burger button being not styled (as per the docs, it's overlaid transparently across all of the screen, so I can click anywhere to open the menu and see that everything else is styled correctly). Is it possible to style the burger button in this fashion or do I have to use the outer `div`? Here is how I've tried to solve this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { slide as BurgerMenu } from 'react-burger-menu';
import styled from 'styled-components';


const StyledBurgerMenu = styled(BurgerMenu)`
  /* Position and sizing of burger button */
  .bm-burger-button {
    position: fixed;
    width: 36px;
    height: 30px;
    left: 36px;
    top: 36px;
  }

  /* Color/shape of burger icon bars */
  .bm-burger-bars {
    background: #373a47;
  }

  /* Position and sizing of clickable cross button */
  .bm-cross-button {
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
  }

  /* Color/shape of close button cross */
  .bm-cross {
    background: #bdc3c7;
  }

  /* General sidebar styles */
  .bm-menu {
    background: #373a47;
    padding: 2.5em 1.5em 0;
    font-size: 1.15em;
  }

  /* Morph shape necessary with bubble or elastic */
  .bm-morph-shape {
    fill: #373a47;
  }

  /* Wrapper for item list */
  .bm-item-list {
    color: #b8b7ad;
    padding: 0.8em;
  }

  /* Individual item */
  .bm-item {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  /* Styling of overlay */
  .bm-overlay {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
`;


export class Menu extends React.Component {
  showSettings(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <StyledBurgerMenu>
        <a id="home" className="menu-item" href="/">Home</a>
        <a id="about" className="menu-item" href="/about">About</a>
      </StyledBurgerMenu>
    );
  }
}

export default Menu;
```

Thanks!

Comment: If `<BurgerMenu/>` isn't already an instance of a styled component, you have to wrap it. No way around that.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to style the burger button in this fashion or do I have
>   to use the outer div?

By passing your `BurgerMenu` to styled, you are not adding an outer div, the styled component only ensures your css is added to the document and passes the `className` to `BurgerMenu`. So in order for this to work, `BurgerMenu` has to render its `className` prop. If it does that it will work without an outer div (or any other parent).

According to https://github.com/negomi/react-burger-menu/blob/95a58dd41e546730f5661dd7ad8deb7296a725ff/src/menuFactory.js#L251 it assigns its `className` prop to an inner div, which is not ideal for `styled-components` but your styles will apply to that `div`. If you want to style the other elements at or above that level, you will either need to come up with some fancy selectors or assign them from outside.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because of [the way styled-components work](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#styling-normal-react-components)

The styling is being applied to a child div, not the outer div:
[Link to code in react-burger-menu](https://github.com/negomi/react-burger-menu/blob/master/src/menuFactory.js#L245)